# Place 4 figures side by side in 2-column latex document

Tags: subfig

I am trying to put four figures side by side in a two column latex document to do so I am using this code. But it's not working. Where am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{scale=0.1}
        \includegraphics{BFS6MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison1 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:6MB_BFS}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{scale=0.1}
        \includegraphics{BFS25MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison2 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:25MB_bfs}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{scale=0.1}
        \includegraphics{MM6MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison3 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:6MB_mm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{scale=0.1}
        \includegraphics{MM25MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison4 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:25MB_mm}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Four Figures}
        \label{fig:four figures}
\end{figure}
```

I am using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`

[image: Generated Page]

Comment: What is not working here? Can you provide an image of the output? Also, what `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I am using ```\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}```

Comment: Added the figure

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5):

> Where am I [g]oing wrong?

- Use a `figure*` environment, not a `figure` environment, to typeset the figure object across both columns of the two-column environment.
- You should load the `subcaption` package, not the `subfig` package. Actually, it's not clear from your write-up as to which one of these two packages you load. However, you did set the `subfig` tag, and this makes me think that there's an issue with the package that should be loaded to create subfigures.
- The instruction `\begin{subfigure}[b]{scale=0.1}` cannot be correct. It should probably be

  ```
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
  ```

  Observe that the mandatory argument of the `subfigure` environment is a length variable, not a scalar.
- The instructions `\includegraphics{...}` need to be augmented. They should probably be

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}
  ```
- Delete the second of the three `\qquad` instructions and replace the other two with `\hfill` ("horizontal fill").
- Not an error but an inaccuracy (and redundancy): the `\centering` instruction isn't needed if the subfigures are supposed to span the full width of the two-column text block -- which I assume is the case here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,demo]{IEEEtran} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    %\centering % Not needed
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{BFS6MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison1 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:6MB_BFS}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{BFS25MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison2 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:25MB_bfs}
    \end{subfigure}
    %% leave a blank line to create a line break

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{MM6MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison3 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:6MB_mm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{MM25MB.png}
        \caption{Comparison4 of large caption dfdfd rates dfdfB dfdfd dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdf}
        \label{fig:25MB_mm}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Four Figures}
    \label{fig:four figures}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```